# Elegant method of running function with multiple single value outputs per factor on data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have found a method of using `list` within a `data.table` object in R to calculate the Shapiro Wilkes test for normality per factor.

```
irisDT <- data.table(iris)
irisDT[, list(sw_results = shapiro.test(Petal.Width)), by = Species]
```

Technically this is correct, the values are run per factor. However, the output is not particularly 'neat' IMHO. It outputs a `data.table` of length 12, with 2 columns. The first column identifying the species, the second (created as `sw_results`) lists all the details of the test - the statistic, p-value, method and data.name.

How can I modify this code to instead output a `data.table` of 3 rows, with separate columns per item with rows per factor?

I am aware that I can then reshape the data through another command, however, this would be an added frustration if the data set was large. Is there a way to modify the line with the calculation to achieve this?

I had a hunch with `lapply` in the form of:

```
irisDT[, lapply(.SD$Petal.Width, shapiro.test), by = Species]
```

however I am getting an error message "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : sample size must be between 3 and 5000". `irisDT` in full is only 150 rows, so I am slightly confused about this response. Is my `lapply` wrongly implemented? Is there another method that would better achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
irisDT[, shapiro.test(Petal.Width), by = Species]
```

This gives you

```
      Species statistic      p.value                      method   data.name
1:     setosa 0.7997645 8.658573e-07 Shapiro-Wilk normality test Petal.Width
2: versicolor 0.9476263 2.727780e-02 Shapiro-Wilk normality test Petal.Width
3:  virginica 0.9597715 8.695419e-02 Shapiro-Wilk normality test Petal.Width
```

Comment: Wow, simple obvious answer. I need to learn to stop over-thinking these things and let data.table do it's work. Thank you.